# remove lines in txt file based on pattern

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a txt file with contents similar to

```
    value1 has output a123
    a123 has output 90
    a123 has output 5000
    a123 has output 400
    value2 has output 100
    value3 has output a133
    a133 has output 50
    a133 has output 90
    value4 has output a223
    a223 has output 100
```

I want to remove lines that are repeating twice (lines that appear in last word of previous line ) like--

```
 a123 has output 90
 a123 has output 5000
 a123 has output 400
 a133 has output 50
 a133 has output 90
 a223 has output 100
```

and kept these--

```
value1 has output a123
value2 has output 100
value3 has output a133 
value4 has output a223
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: i tried using awk nf but can't make the proper output.

Comment: @AmarjitSingh, either your tried code is working or not still you have to add codes to your post as we all are here to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `awk` command will do:

```
awk '$1!=l{print;l=$NF}' your_text_file
```

Comment: yeah it removes but i can't get the right output because there is multiple outputs . changing to reflect in question .

Comment: The code actually works for your updated input as well.

Comment: Never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want to get the value from line which starts from string `value` then following may help you too.

```
awk '/^value/{value=$NF} $1!=value'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;N;s/((\S+)\s*)\n\s*\2\s.*/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Compare the following line with the previous and if the last word of the following line is the same as the last word of the previous, remove the following line and repeat.